# Save image with Tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I implemented Tinymce on a website and it's being used as a content editor by the owner of the website (the content is saved in a .txt file). I would like to know if it is possible to save an image uploaded in the tinymce editor into a specific folder on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to choose a specific location for image uploading using the `images_upload_url` property. You can read more on that and our Image Uploading API here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/